# Is there a reason why handler functions are added differently from custom driver functions?

Tags: python, drivers, development

If I add a handler, I use:

```
bpy.app.handlers.handlertype.append(captainFuture)
```

If I want to remove it, I usually use the cheap way out since I still haven't learned to do it properly (I was young and I needed the money):

```
bpy.app.handlers.handlertype.clear()
```

Usable hack on a remote island but if by chance any addon or script uses the same handler, then disaster ensues.

Now, with drivers it's so much easier for this addled brain of mine:

Creation:

```
bpy.app.driver_namespace['curtis'] = captainFuture
```

Deletion:

```
del(bpy.app.driver_namespace['curtis'])
```

Nothing to remember but a string and a location.

Is there a binding reason why both approaches are different? Or asked differently and selfishly: Why not use dictionaries all the time?

Answer (score 2):

Handlers are callback handlers that work on application level. Drivers work on data level. What does this mean?

`app.handlers` also work without having any data to work with. For `drivers` you will always need to add the driver to existing data in blender. For example an attribute on your object.

The `app.driver_namespace` contains some value modification functions you can use within your drivers. By itself it doesn't do a thing. It needs to be triggered by the animation system.

```
def mul2(value): return value*2
bpy.app.driver_namespace['my_function'] = mul2
```

Now you can use this function inside a driver python expression

```
#my_function(var)
```